# Unable to uninstall GStreamer multimedia codec

Tags: software-center, uninstall, gstreamer

Every time I try to uninstall GStreamer Multimedia Codecs from the Ubuntu Software Centre, it tells me I can't uninstall GStreamer Multimedia Codecs as its `held by process 44958 (apt)`.

In the terminal it tells me that permission is denied, and I can't even power off or restart my device.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu is probably updating package info, updating packages.
Best thing would be to wait.
You could also forcefully terminate the `apt` processes by running the below from a terminal:

```
sudo killall apt apt-get
```